# ASP.NET web forms website performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis

I acquired an ASP.NET web forms website built by some contract developers.  The site was pretty bad at first and ran pretty slow, but has been tweaked and in an isolated environment runs okay.

The site sits on a single (beefy) web server and connects to an Oracle database.  The site is within a very large organizations data center but is not load balanced.  Lately the site has received about 3-4x the traffic it typically sees and the site is crawling with about 4k unique users a day.  IIS6 by the way.  The IT dept. has examined the CPU and memory levels and they appear fine.  I know there are some other tweaks I can make to IIS to cache static files and I am adding OutputCache to controls where it makes sense.  However, what else could be the cause of a slowdown that appears to be caused by load?  I'm unsure if the application pool needs more memory allocated or if the site is simply a piece of junk.  I know the latter is true, but it surprises me that significant load would be a code-only issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bad sql queries. Our contractors are known for just frankenstein-ing sql together and it runs sooooo slow.

Comment: Also, is this a web site "project" (File->Add Web Site), or a web application project (File->Add Project)?

Comment: It's very difficult to say without seeing the problem. If you are using Entity Framework, it's easy to get some horrendous queries without realizing it. To make the site faster, I would port to MVC.

Comment: One good place to start is to trace through and figure out how many (and which) queries are running per user interaction. I inherited a project once and found that 20+ queries ran right after login... and by the time they were on a report page it was over 50... Same logic/queries were getting called in multiple places. Clearing those up and tweaking crap queries helped.

Comment: There's not enough information here to go on. My first suspicion is that the SQL queries are running synchronously. This is an old post, but still relevant and might be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx I'd also recommend looking into performance counters. You need to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I know there's not a lot of info here, I was just going for a big picture view to see if I was missing an obvious culprit.  Yes, the SQL is bad but I don't have a DBA to truly take a hard look at it.  I know MS SQL better than I do Oracle.

This is a web application project - compiled in advance.

Comment: I would take a look at examining the entire architecture of the website.  Is it mainly a database driven website without any heavy server side processing then I would first look at the database.  I would think a google search and reading a little you can find some oracle DB tuning tips similar to Sql Server.  Take a look at some slow pages and start running through the queries.  If there is heavy server side processing you may have to start looking and removing that processing in separate services and consider a more service oriented and maybe multi-threaded solution.  Good Luck!

Comment: I think you should check following things: 1) hardware/internet connection, 2) website page, 3) connection between application and database(I mean query, transaction), 4) database(indexes -nightmare).
First you should start check hardware(You did it), then database(indexes) and how application communicate with database(profiler) and at the end check application(source code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to see if indexes are applied to the queries/store procedures being run.  Also, see if the page is doing selects or update/deletes.  When you apply indexes it can slow down the deletes/update and spreeds up the selects.

Usually there are profilers in the database that can be ran on the queries and they will indicate what indexes should be applied to what table.  See you Database admin to see if that can be ran on the store procedures you use.

Comment: I've been using SQL Developer's Tuning Advisor tool and adding indexes.  That looks to be helping things a bit.